# Auto Layout manipulating object created in IB through code

Tags: objective-c, ios8, autolayout

I asked a more general question in a previous thread about converting to Auto Layout, but as I'm doing the conversion I've run into something very specific.

I have a base class VC that handles getting text fields and views out of the way when the keyboard pops up.  It also does the same with date pickers and picker views.  So if the VC has a date picker, then in IB a date picker is created, and it's Y value in the frame is set to be just off the bounds of the main view.  There is an IBOutlet that it is connected to in the base class, and then in the code [self showDatePicker] is called, and the base class does everything else.  Works great.

Enter Auto Layout.  Even though constraints are generated at runtime for the date picker, since I don't create any, it still seems to work by manipulating the frame, i.e. the picker still animates up and down the screen when it is called or dismissed.

In trying to convert that to Auto Layout, I added a new constraint in code which binds the top of the view to the Top Layout Guide.  This works fine, except for the error messages in the debugger that a constraint has to be broken, since one already exists, (created at runtime) for this.

I'd like to avoid having to manually create the constraints on the picker, and then bind one to a property, but it seems the only way around that is to go through the list of constraints on the main view, find the specific one for the top binding of the picker, and then manipulate that.  But I don't see a convenient way to find specific constraint, especially one generated at runtime.

So, any thoughts on this?  Should I just add the constraints on the picker and attach the top one to a property?  Leaving it as it is doesn't seem like a good option, as this is the first time I've seen adjusting the frame work with constraints...

Comment: Why don't you just create constraints on the date pickerin the storyboard (or xib)?

Comment: @rfj001 no, that's actually not true at all.

Comment: "Should I just add the constraints on the picker and attach the top one to a property?" -- yes, that's what you should do.

Comment: Have you considered adding IBOutlets to the constraints you've built in the storyboard? Then you can animate/manipulate the constraint constant in the keyboard change events?

Comment: yes, that is what i will end up doing.  thanks...